# Widget to show calendar events and TODO items merged in a single agenda?

Tags: calendar, app-widgets, google-calendar, to-do-list

The Calendar application works with Google Calendar and its agenda style is really useful. Nevertheless, for some reason, it does not work with Google Tasks, so I use GTasks that works with the Google Tasks. I use both of them really intensively, but none of them can show both calendar events and todo items. Sometimes it's very inconvenient because I have to switch between widgets and merge the overall timeline in my mind.

So is there any widget to show calendar events and TODO items at once? Agenda style would be a real plus.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Pure Calendar Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.koxx.pure_calendar). Will cost you about two bucks, but does exactly what you request:

> Widget for Agenda / Tasks / TODO (agenda style)
>
> - Synced with Google calendars
> - Show calendars from Google, TouchDown & Moto/LG Exchange
> - Show tasks from Astrid, Tasks (Team), MyPhoneExplorer, Ultimate To-Do List, TaskSync, CalenGoo, DGT Gtd, gTasks, Got To Do, Task Organizer, Due Today, TouchDown, Pocket Informant

[image: Pure Calendar Widget] [image: Agenda Widget for Android]
<sup>Pure Calendar Widget / Agenda Widget for Android (source: Google Play; click image for larger variant)</sup>

An alternative could be [Agenda Widget for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roflharrison.agenda) (second screenshot above), which has a free trial variant (which I linked) and comes close to what the previously mentioned does.

As I don't use any of those, I cannot tell you which might fit you best -- but at least with the free variant, you might want to give it a try :)

Comment: Yes, I saw Pure Calendar Widget either, and I hoped that there are still some candidates except of it. I'm just playing with Agenda Widget, and it looks pretty amazing and highly customizable (for example, you can set set a custom date/time range -- the Calendar widget simply offers one week). So it really seems to be worthy for giving a try. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just curious @izzy why you don't seem to feel this question is off-topic as "Can you recommend an app which does X?" Is it specific enough?

Comment: @TreborRude Actually, it's border-lining (and I thought about that hint, yes). But it's easily re-phrased to "How can I display that info together in one place, so I don't have to switch around". While in such cases I usually *do* the actual re-phrasing, I missed it here as I was short on time (had to switch offices, so I had to decide between placing the answer and re-phrasing the question)...

Answer (score 1):

Try Jorte Calendar. It merges Google Calendar and Tasks flawlessely

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.johospace.jorte&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I use Simple Calendar Widget.

Different skins
* Possibility to choose which calendars to show 
* Font style and background customization 
* Show or hide current day of month
* Possibility to choose which application to open
* Support of tasks using Dato **GTasks** or Astrid

I cannot post images but here is a link to the app: [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anod.calendar&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hbm9kLmNhbGVuZGFyIl0.)