# How to export a google keep todo list to google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, google-keep

I use google keep as a todo list and I want to export it to google calendars so I know what to do during the day. I also use the always on display to see what events/tasks are needed during the day. How would this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Do list cannot be exported

Only reminders can be exported - see [Google help](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/kmI_oLxh79M)

So instead of to-do mark them as reminders and switch the calendar to show reminders or else try the  solution mentioned here [Widget to show calendar events and TODO items merged in a single agenda?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44440/131553)

Comment: see [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/reminders-make-google-calendar-incredible-list/) for more help

Comment: Ah, I see this is probably as good as it's going to get. Thanks!